# tweets about dengue in Brazil: top 10 people

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using tweepy to get tweets about dengue in Brazil.
I am interesting in getting recent tweets about the 10 people with the most followers. I use the search api, not streaming api, because I don't need all the tweets, just the most relevant.

I am surprised to get so few tweets (only 17). Should I use the streaming api instead?

Here is my code:

```
#api access
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_token_key=""
access_token_secret=""

import csv
#write results in file
writer= csv.writer(open(r"twitter.csv", "wt"), lineterminator='\n', delimiter =';')
writer.writerow(["date", "langage", "place", "country", "username", "nb_followers", "tweet_text"])


import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#get tweets for Brazil only
places = api.geo_search(query="Brazil", granularity="country")
place_id = places[0].id
print(place_id)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="dengue+OR+%23dengue&place:" + place_id, since="2015-08-01", until="2015-08-25").items():
    date=tweet.created_at
    langage=tweet.lang
    try:
        place=tweet.place.full_name
        country=tweet.place.country
    except:
        place=None
        country=None

    username=tweet.user.screen_name
    nb_followers=tweet.user.followers_count
    tweet_text=tweet.text.encode('utf-8')

    print("created on", tweet.created_at)
    print("langage", tweet.lang)
    print("place:", place)
    print("country:", country)
    print("user:", tweet.user.screen_name)
    print("nb_followers:", tweet.user.followers_count)
    print(tweet.text.encode("utf-8"))
    print('')

    writer.writerow([date, langage, place, country, username, nb_followers, tweet_text])
```

Comment: don't use a bar `except` like that - you may well be masking important errors. at the very least log the traceback. in this case you should probably catch `AttributeError` and allow everything else to propagate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is: The `place` attribute is rarely present in the data. Thus very few tweets are returned.

I am now using the `lang` attribute with `pt` value (their is no `pt-br` langage unfortunately). It's not exactly what I want since it returns tweets from other countries such as Portugal but it's so far the best I could find.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="dengue+OR+%23dengue", lang="pt", since=date, until=end_date).items():
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the search manually and seeing what you get. It sounds like your application is appropriate for the search API.